# Tengo problemas con mi responsive web

Tags: html, css, mediaqueries

Estoy realizando una web a pantalla completa en sentido vertical, en versión escritorio todo sale muy bien, pero a la hora de plantearlo como responsive, las secciones se sobreponen unas sobre otras.
Tal vez tengo un error, aqui pueden ver mi codigo.
LAs primeras dos secciones se acomodán, pero cuando inicio la tercera, esta se sobrepone sobre la segunda y asi con la cuarta.
También las imágenes no se adecuan al tamaño que les doy, aun utilizando la etiquet scrset y tengo las imagenes en version mobile para ello.

Por otro lado, en los simuladores de telefonos pareciera que el scroll no funcionara.

Por favor, me podrían dar una ayuda, dado que tengo cita con el cliente el día de mañana y le quiero mostrar la version mobil.
He intentado implementando tailwind en un backup pero no funciona bien. Quiero hacerlo a codigo puro para tener mas control.
Gracias.

Y también porque no funciona mi etiqueta

```css
* {
        margin: 0 ;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }



    body {
        background: #000;
        color: #fff;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    header {
       
        height: 100px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 999;
        width: 100vw;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        
    }
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }

    .logo {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        width: 250px;
        padding: 1rem 1rem;
    }
    .reservas {
        background-color: var(--red-color);
        position: fixed;
        right: -35px;
        bottom: 30%;
        width: 120px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 6px 6px  0  0;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        transform: rotate(-90deg); 
        z-index: 999;
        

    }
    @media (max-width: 991px) {
        .reservas {
            background-color: var(--red-color);
            position: fixed;
            right: -35px;
            top: 70%;
            width: 120px;
            height: 50px;
            border-radius: 6px 6px  0  0;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            transform: rotate(-90deg);
            float: right;
        
        }
    }


    .hamburger-menu {
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        top: 1.5rem;
        right: 1.5rem;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 2;
        
       }
       
       .line {
        width: 30px;
        height: 3px;
        background-color: var(--red-color);
        margin: 6px 0;
        transition: 0.4s;
       }

    .main-menu {
        list-style: none;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: var(--red-color);
        opacity: .7;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        transform: translateY(100%);
        transition: transform 0.3s;
        justify-content: center;

    }

    .main-menu--show {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    .main-menu__item {
        padding: 1em;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .main-menu__link {
        color: #fff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-decoration: none;
    }



    .container {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: flex;
    }

    .container section {
        min-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
        /*z-index: 9;*/

    }


    .smoke_video.show {
        opacity: .3;
        
    }
    .smoke_video {
        bottom: 0;
        height: auto;
        left: 0;
        mix-blend-mode: plus-lighter;
        object-fit: fill;
        pointer-events: none;
        position: fixed;
        transition: opacity 2s;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 4;
        animation-duration: 5s;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        animation-name: video;
        
    }
    video {

        object-fit: contain;
        overflow: clip;
       

    }

    @keyframes video {
        0% {opacity: .3;}
        50% {opacity: .2;}
        100% {opacity: 0;}
    }



    @media (max-width: 991px) {
        .container {
            position: absolute;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            height: auto;
            transform: none !important;
        }

    }

    .content {
        display: contents;
    }

    .carousel {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        z-index: -1;
       }
       
       .carousel-item {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
       }
       
       .carousel-item.active {
        opacity: 1;
       }
       
       .carousel-item img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        object-fit: cover;
       }
       




    /* Frame 1 = home page */
    .frame_1 {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas: 'cta logo';
        grid-auto-rows: 1fr 1fr;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;

    }
    .frame_col_1 {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: end;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        padding-bottom: 3rem;
        grid-area: 'cta';

    }
    .frame_col_1 p {
        font-family: var(--logo-font);
        font-size: clamp(1rem, 2vw, 1.7rem);
        padding: 1.5rem;
    }
    .frame_col_1 .btn {
        font-family: var(--main-text);
        padding: 1.3rem;
        border: 1px solid var(--white);
        color: white;
        width: 250px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        z-index: 1000;
    }

    .frame_col_1 .btn:hover {
        background-color: var(--red-color);
        transition: ease-in-out .5s;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .frame_col_2 {
        grid-area: 'logo';
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .frame_col_2 h2 {
         font-family: var(--logo-font);
         font-size: clamp(1.5rem, 5vw, 3rem);
         color: var(--white);
         padding-bottom: 1rem;
    }
    .frame_col_2 h1 {
        font-family: var(--barrio-text);
        color: var(--red-color);
        font-size: clamp(4rem, calc(30vw + 1rem), 14rem);
        margin: 0;
    }
    .frame_1_redline {
        width: 480px;
        margin-top: -40px;
    }
    .cuerpo-texto {
        width: 50%;
        line-height: 2rem;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: clamp(1.2rem, 5vw, 1.25rem);
        font-family: var(--main-text);
    }

    @media (max-width: 991px){
        .frame_1 {
            grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr
        
        }
        .frame_col_1 {
            grid-row: 2;
            grid-area: 'cta';
        
        }
        .frame_col_2 {
            grid-row: 1;
            grid-area: 'logo';
            margin-top: calc(25% + 0.5rem);
            align-self: flex-end;
        }
        .cuerpo-texto {
            width: 100%;
            line-height: 1.25rem;
            padding: 10px;
            
        }
        .frame_1_redline {
            width: 50%;
            margin-top: -20px;
        }

    }

    /* FRAME 2 - Empezamos con el segundo frame */

    .frame_2 {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(310px, 1fr));
        /*grid-auto-rows: 1fr;*/
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;   

    }
    .frame_2_col_1 {
        grid-column: 1 / 2;
        background-image: url('/img/imagen-principal-segunda.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        grid-row: span 2;
    }
    .frame_2_image {
        object-fit: cover;

    }
    .frame_2_image img {
        height: 100vh;
        object-fit: cover;
    }

    .frame_2_text {
        grid-column: span 1;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        
    }
    .frame_2_text h2 {
        font-family: var(--barrio-text);
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: clamp(4rem, calc(30vw + 1rem), 8rem);
        line-height: .8;
        margin-left: -300px;
        
    }
    .frame_2_text div:nth-child(2) {
        margin-right: 2vw;
        padding-bottom: 2rem;
    }

    .frame_2_col_3 {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        padding: 2rem;
        align-items: center;
        grid-row: span 2;
        & p {
            font-family: var(--main-text);
            font-size: 1.2rem;
            line-height: 1.5;
            text-align: right;
        }
    }
    .frame_2_row {
        grid-row: 2/3;
      grid-column: 2 /3;
      align-self: flex-end;
    }


    @media (max-width: 991px){
        .frame_2 {
            grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
        }
        .frame_2_image {
            height: fit-content;
            object-fit: cover;
        }
        .frame_2_col_1 {
            grid-row: 1 / 2 ;
            height: 460px;
            background: url('/img/eres-barrio-image.png') no-repeat center;
            background-size: cover;
            grid-column: 1 / -1;
        }
        .frame_2_text {
            grid-column: 1fr;
            grid-row: 2 / 3;
            width: 100%;
            margin-top: -20px;
            grid-column: 1 / -1;
            & h2 {
                margin: 0;
                text-align: center;
                
            }
        }
        .frame_2_row {
            grid-row: 4 / 5;
            grid-column: 1 / -1;
        }
        .frame_2_col_3 {
            grid-row: 3 / 4;
            grid-column: 1 / -1;
        }
    }
    .frame_3 {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
        padding: 0 10px;
        gap: 16px;
        height: 100vh;
    }
    .frame_3_col_1 {
        grid-column: 1 / 2;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 0 1rem 0 1rem;
        height: 100vh;
        & h2 {
            font-family: var(--barrio-text);
            color: var(--red-color);
            font-size: clamp(3rem, calc(23vw + 1rem), 4rem);
        }
        & p {
            font-family: var(--main-text);
            line-height: 1.5;
            font-size: 1.2rem;
        }
    }
    .frame_3_col_2 {
        grid-column: 2 / 3;
        display: flex;
        align-content: center;

    }
    .frame_3_col_2 img {
        height: 450px;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
    .frame_3_img {
        width: 650px;
        height: 450px;
        object-fit: cover;
    }

    .frame_3_col_3 {
        grid-column: 3/4;
        display: flex;
      justify-content: end;
    }

    .frame_3_col_3 img {
        height: 100vh;
        object-fit: cover;
    }

    @media (max-width: 991px) {
        .frame_3{
            grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
            grid-template-columns: 1fr;
            margin-top: 25vh;
        }
        .frame_3_col_2 {
            grid-row: 1 / 2;
            grid-column: 1 / -1;
            margin-top: calc(33% + 1rem);
        }
        .frame_3_col_2 img {
            height: auto;
            object-fit: cover;
        }

        .frame_3_col_3 {
            grid-row: 2 / 3;
            grid-column: 1 / -1;
        }
        .frame_3_col_3 img {
            height: 300px;
            width: fit-content;
        }

        .frame_3_col_1 {
            grid-row: 3 / 4;
            grid-column: 1 / -1;
            height: auto;
        }
    }

    .frame_4 {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .frame_4_col_2 .btn {
        font-family: var(--main-text);
        padding: 1.3rem;
        border: 1px solid var(--white);
        color: white;
        width: 250px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

```html
<header>
            <nav class="main-nav">
                <div class="logo"><img src="img/LOGO.svg" width="150px" alt=""></div>
                <div id="toggle-menu" class="hamburger-menu">
                    <div class="line"></div>
                    <div class="line"></div>
                    <div class="line"></div>
                </div>
                <ul id="main-menu" class="main-menu">
                    <li class="main-menu__item"><a href="#" class="main-menu__link">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="main-menu__item"><a href="#" class="main-menu__link">About</a></li>
                    <li class="main-menu__item"><a href="#" class="main-menu__link">Blog</a></li>
                    <li class="main-menu__item"><a href="#" class="main-menu__link">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

        </header>
        <div class="reservas">
            <p>RESERVAS</p>
        </div>
        <video class="show smoke_video" preload autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" playsinline muted>
            <source src="img/smoke.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
       
        <div class="container" data-0="transform:translateX(0%)" data-4000="transform:translateX(-300%)">
            <section>            
                <div class="content">
                        <div class="carousel">
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                               <img src="img/home-main-image.png" alt="Image 2">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                   <img src="img/home-image-hero.png" alt="Image 1">
                            </div>   
                            <div class="frame_1">
                        <div class="frame_col_1">
                            <p>abrimos todos los días</p>
                            <a class="btn" href="#carta">Ver Carta</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="frame_col_2">
                            <h2>un dragón con</h2>
                            <h1>BARRIO</h1>
                            <img class="frame_1_redline" src="img/red-line.png" alt="" />
                            <p class="cuerpo-texto">Más de un siglo de una fusión totalmente mágica, podemos afirmar que esta es nuestra comida, nuestro legado. <br>Somos un restaurante peruano con sabor oriental. </p>
                        </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section>
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="frame_2">
                        <div class="frame_2_col_1">
                            <div class="frame_2_image">                           
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="frame_2_text">
                            <h2>¿y tù <br>eres barrio?</h2>
                            <div><img src="img/red-line.png" width="230px" alt=""></div>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="frame_2_row"><img src="img/mobile-chifa-1.png" height="260px"></div>
                        <div class="frame_2_col_3">
                            <p>El barrio marcó a muchas personas de una generación, y esto se está perdiendo.
                                No queremos ser solo un restaurante, queremos ser parte de una historia que no podemos olvidar, algo que la tecnología y el tiempo nos quitó, queremos regresar a esa unión de amigos, familias, amigos familias que teníamos y que todavía tenemos.</p>
                        </div>                   
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section>
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="frame_3">
                        <div class="frame_3_col_1">
                            <h2>visita nuestro barrio</h2>
                            <p>La hora de comer siempre era sagrada.
                                Toda la familia debía estar presente.
                                Durante la semana, siempre comíamos en nuestras casas comida casera, pero apenas llegaba el fin de semana, ¡uy!, salíamos a degustar esos platos que no se preparaban en casa.</p>
                                <p>
                                Esos platos que no son caseros, pero saben a hogar.
                                </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="frame_3_col_2">
                           <img srcset="
                           img/visita-mesero-400.png 400w"
                           sizes="(max-width:991px) 400w"
                           src="img/visita-mesero-650w.png" alt="Visita nuestro barrio" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="frame_3_col_3">
                            <img 
                                srcset="img/visita-banner-derecho-800w.png 800w"
                                sizes="(max-width: 991px) 800w"
                                src="img/visita-banner-derecho.png" alt="Visite nuestro barrio" />

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section>
                <div id="carta" class="content">
                    <div class="frame_4">
                        <div class="frame_4_col_1">
                            <img src="img/mobile-chifa-1.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="frame_4_col_2">
                            <img src="img/dragon.png" alt="">
                            <h2>Barrio Dragon</h2>
                            <a class="btn" href="#">Ver Carta</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="frame_4_col_3">
                            <div class="carta_menu">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</li>
                                    <li>Aliquid, recusandae delectus.</li>
                                    <li>Animi, ex accusantium?</li>
                                    <li>Dolores, fugit sequi.</li>
                                    <li>Rem, atque delectus.</li>
                                    <li>Veritatis, impedit laborum.</li>
                                    <li>Unde, eligendi aliquid.</li>
                                    <li>Quae, animi iste!</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

        </div>
```

Comment: Acá no hay urgencias, así que cuando alguien quiera y pueda ayudarte lo hará. PD: Porque no te ahorras todo el trabajo y usas Bootstrap u otro??

Comment: Como dice @OCHOA, no te compliques la vida, usa mejor Bootstrap ya trae el uso de columnas para el disenio responsibo. Ademas de tener mejor estilo

Comment: @OCHOA, disculpa si me malinterprete en mis comentarios. Si conozco las reglas que si alguien quere ayudarme lo hará. Agradezco tu comentario sobre usar bootstrap, pero solo queria saber si mi codigo tiene un error, para que no posicione los grids de forma correcta. Gracias.

Comment: Es que obviamente error tiene porque no hace lo que se supone debe hacer. Si es por aprender adelante, puede que alguien te ayude, pero considera la sabana de CSS que has puesto. Pero si lo que quieres es diseñar algo piensa en usar Bootstrap o similares. Salu2...